Comparing dataframes with 2 different number of columns
I need to compare 2 dataframes with different columns and find differences between them.
While this example is numeric, my data is not, I am using this as a sample dataset.
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrames
ProdDF = pd.DataFrame({'Project.name': ['Project A', 'Project B', 'Project C', 'Project D'],
                'Line identifier': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                'Column1': [10, 20, 30, 40],
                'Column2': [100, 200, 300, 400]})

TestDF = pd.DataFrame({'Project.name': ['Project A', 'Project B', 'Project C', 'Project E'],
                'Line identifier': [1, 2, 3, 5],
                'Column1': [10, 20, 35, 45],
                'Column2': [100, 200, 350, 450],
                'Column3': [100, 200, 350, 450]})

key_columns = ['Project.name', 'Line identifier']

# Merge DataFrames on key columns
merged_df = pd.merge(ProdDF, TestDF, on=key_columns, how='outer', suffixes=('_Prod', 
    '_Test'))

print(merged_df)

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Row', 'Column', 'Misaligned Data'])

for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    for column in merged_df.columns:
        if column not in key_columns:
            prod_column = column + '_Prod'
            test_column = column + '_Test'

            if prod_column in merged_df.columns and test_column in merged_df.columns:
                if row[prod_column] != row[test_column]:
                    output = output.append({'Row': index, 'Column': column, 'Misaligned Data': (row[prod_column], row[test_column])}, ignore_index=True)

print(output)

This gives me the following output:
Project.name  Line identifier  Column1_Prod  Column2_Prod  Column1_Test  Column2_Test  
Column3
0    Project A                1          10.0         100.0          10.0         100.0    
100.0
1    Project B                2          20.0         200.0          20.0         200.0    
200.0
2    Project C                3          30.0         300.0          35.0         350.0    
350.0

I would like the output to be:
Project.Name, Line identifier Prod Test
Project C       3              30   35
Project A       1              100   NaN
Project A       2              200   NaN
Project A       3              250   NaN

I am only looking for the differences between dataframes.

You can change your loop to try this instead, comparing columns from the Prod dataframe in order to find the differences with the merged_df
formatted_output = []

for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    # compare columns from ProdDF
    for column in ProdDF.columns.difference(key_columns):
        prod_column = column + '_Prod'
        test_column = column + '_Test'

        # Check if both columns are in the merged DataFrame
        if prod_column in merged_df.columns or test_column in merged_df.columns:
            prod_value = row[prod_column] if prod_column in merged_df.columns else None
            test_value = row[test_column] if test_column in merged_df.columns else None

            # compare to find differences
            if prod_value != test_value:
                formatted_output.append({
                    'Project.Name': row['Project.name'],
                    'Line identifier': row['Line identifier'],
                    'Prod': prod_value,
                    'Test': test_value
                })

output_df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_output)

# sort by 'Project.Name' and 'Line identifier'
output_df = output_df.sort_values(by=['Project.Name', 'Line identifier'])

# print DataFrame with formatted output
print(output_df)


After Adding formatted_output = [] a the top, this is awesome, than you so much

df.iterrows is generally inefficient (see here). Instead, prepare your data for use in df.compare:
import pandas as pd

idx = ['Project.name', 'Line identifier']
keys = ('Prod', 'Test')

comp = (pd.concat([df.set_index(idx) for df in [ProdDF, TestDF]],
                  axis=0, 
                  join='inner', 
                  keys=keys
                  )
        .unstack(0)
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .pipe(lambda df: df[keys[0]]
              .compare(df[keys[1]],
                       result_names=keys
                       )
              )
        )

Output:
                             Column1       Column2       
                                Prod  Test    Prod   Test
Project.name Line identifier                             
Project C    3                  30.0  35.0   300.0  350.0
Project D    4                  40.0   NaN   400.0    NaN
Project E    5                   NaN  45.0     NaN  450.0

To match the specific format from your question, add:
comp.stack(0).droplevel(-1).reset_index()

  Project.name  Line identifier   Prod   Test
0    Project C                3   30.0   35.0
1    Project C                3  300.0  350.0
2    Project D                4   40.0    NaN
3    Project D                4  400.0    NaN
4    Project E                5    NaN   45.0
5    Project E                5    NaN  450.0

Explanation / Intermediates

Set idx (your 'key_columns') as index for your dfs with df.set_index.
Concatenate using pd.concat on axis=0.

join='inner' drops columns not in common.
keys=keys tracks the source ('Prod' or 'Test').



# pd.concat(...)

                                   Column1  Column2
     Project.name Line identifier                  
Prod Project A    1                     10      100
     Project B    2                     20      200
     Project C    3                     30      300
     Project D    4                     40      400
Test Project A    1                     10      100
     Project B    2                     20      200
     Project C    3                     35      350
     Project E    5                     45      450


Unstack with df.unstack to move keys index level (0) to columns and swap levels with df.swaplevel to make it the top level of MultiIndex:

# pd.concat(...).unstack(0).swaplevel(axis=1)

                                Prod    Test    Prod    Test
                             Column1 Column1 Column2 Column2
Project.name Line identifier                                
Project A    1                  10.0    10.0   100.0   100.0
Project B    2                  20.0    20.0   200.0   200.0
Project C    3                  30.0    35.0   300.0   350.0
Project D    4                  40.0     NaN   400.0     NaN
Project E    5                   NaN    45.0     NaN   450.0


Use pipe to chain operations, applying df.compare between 'Prod' (df[keys[0]]) and 'Test' (df[keys[1]]).

result_names=keys ensures that these names are used in the result, rather than default 'self' and 'other'.



